# How to add custom metadata using fpm for rpm/deb pacakges

Tags: package, metadata, rpm, deb, fpm

I am trying to create rpm package using fpm command

fpm -s dir -t rpm -n <package_name> -v  -C <src_file_path> --prefix

But I need to add some custom metadata some project specific key, values , I tried with --rpm-attr but not successful :( , When I tried to query them , it was coming line "unknown tag"

I have to give this command with the paths provided , so I haven't used spec file as it possible to give spec(it was not useful for my project for now) and the tool path at a time to make a package.

How can I do that , can any one please help, it means lot to me

thanks in advance

I am trying to create rpm package using fpm command
fpm -s dir -t rpm -n <package_name> -v  -C <src_file_path> --prefix 
But I need to add some custom metadata some project specific key, values , I tried with --rpm-attr but not successful :( , When I tried to query them , it was coming line "unknown tag" I have to give this command with the paths provided , so I haven't used spec file as it possible to give spec(it was not useful for my project for now) and the tool path at a time to make a package. How can I do that , can any one please help, it means lot to me thanks in advance